# Dispose HttpResponseMessage is it good practice?

Tags: c#, httpclient, httpresponsemessage

I am asking this question cause i recently discover that it is not good practice to dispose HttpClient in each request. In other hand it's better to use one instance in whole application.
So my question is, if it is better or not to dispose HttpResponseMessage after each request.
Here is my code:

```
private static HttpClient httpClient= new HttpClient();

private async Task<string> SendRequest()
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage result = await httpClient.GetAsync("www.mysite"))
    {
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: You need to dispose `HttpResponseMessage`. You can't re-use them anyway, so the trying to compare it to `HttpClient` isn't a like-for-like comparison, and is meaningless

Comment: If it implements IDisposable then dispose it.

Comment: Thank you Alex K. So my example is correct right?

Comment: [See this article](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/demystifying-httpclient-internals-httpresponsemessage). The author is very knowledgeable.

Comment: Thank you Crowcoder, article helped me a lot.